# Loading animation in SQL Queries of ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, multithreading, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application written in VB.NET.

On one of my pages, I need to retrieve several sections of data from a SQL database on page load, which takes a long time. These requests are processed one after another, not at the same time.I'm trying to get a loading animation to display when the page is loading, not the usual default blank page in most browsers.

I execute the SQL queries directly in the page's load event. Is there anyway to show a loading animation or `div` when the page is not loaded versus show the actual content when it has completed loading?

Comment: You could open the page without the database queries and use JavaScript on the page to request the data.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this. But it not at all clear why those queries take a long time? They should be looked at, and optimized.

Remember, your code behind NEVER interacts with the user. The page travels up to web server. Code behind runs and can modify anything on the page - when ALL code behind is done, then the WHOLE FRESH new page travels back down to the client side browser. It is then loaded, re-fresher, and then displayed.

So, what this means? You would say put a button on the page (we can hide it), but for testing let the page load - but NOT run your slow data query(s).

Now, when we click on the button, we can have client side browser code display the animation, and then the button's code behind runs. When done, the page will again travel back to client side.

So, we need to (must) have the whole page load first to the client side browser. And then click on a button. Now we can have the user click on that button, or we can get the browser code to click that button. Once we get this working, then we simply hide the button.

so, this means that you have to move out the page load code to behind a simple asp.net button. Get that code working. You can now say do this:

And that ALSO means that by default, we LET THE page display the spinnner. And our code behind button will turn it off!!!

So, we can have this markup (I assume jQquery - don't we all???).

So, this markup:

```
        <div id="MySpinner" runat="server">
            <img src="Content/wait2.gif" />
        </div>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdLoadGrid" runat="server" Text="Button" ClientIDMode="Static" Style="display:none" />

        <div id="MyGrid" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table"></asp:GridView>
        </div>

        <script>

            var isPostBack = <%=Convert.ToString(Page.IsPostBack).ToLower()%>;

            $(document).ready(function () {
                if (isPostBack == false) {
                   $('#cmdLoadGrid').click()
                }
            })
        </script>
```

So, the spinner gif is in plain view. Page loads - display spinner, and THEN we use JavaScript to click the button to load the grid.

Our code behind thus looks like this:

```
Protected Sub cmdLoadGrid_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLoadGrid.Click

    Thread.Sleep(4000)    ' for testing = remove

    Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City from tblHotels"

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)

            conn.Open()
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

    ' hide the spinner
    MySpinner.Style("Display") = "none"
    MyGrid.Style("Display") = "normal"

End Sub
```

So, note how we placed the spinner in a "div" - server tag so our simple code behind can run - load grid, and then show grid, hide spinner.

So, wire up the button - get it working. AND THEN hide it with display:none. We also added a custom js function to get isPostBack - since JavaScript does not have that feature/function.

However, I would take a close look as to why those queries you have are taking so long - they probably should not.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation. I will look at threading of the application and postbacks. Regarding the SQL queries, I have to execute around 20 SQL requests at max, which are done asynchronously, which I believe is taking up most of the load time. It would be nice if I could execute all of these requests ast the same time.

Comment: Well, maybe - but until all code behind is done running - the web page is stuck up on the server - and even with await and async calls - if you put in awaits - your still waiting, and your page can't travel back to the end user anyway. You could perhaps start multiple separate threads to speed this up, but with multiple separate threads, then you going to have a rather difficult time to get that information back into the one page. Now, without question, you could have the page load, and then do separate ajax calls to get the data - but you have to write and wire up quite a bit of js code.